# Reusable code soap client laravel

Tags: php, laravel, soap, traits, reusability

I have different functions that use the same soap client in laravel:
The duplicate code for the soapclient in these functions seems wrong. 
I tried with a trait file but I don't seem to get it working that way.

```
 public function getStaff()
    {
        // INITIALISEER DE SOAP CLIENT
        $webservicesPwd = "apipwd";      
        $soap = new SoapClient('https://apiserver.com');

        // HAAL STUDENTEN OP VIA API CALL
        $result = $soap->apiFunction($webservicesPwd,2,1);

        // INDIEN RESULTAAT NIET CORRECT
        if(is_int($result)) {

           throw new \Exception($errorMessage);
        }
```

And

```
public function getStudents()
    {
          // INITIALISEER DE SOAP CLIENT
        $webservicesPwd = "apipwd";      
        $soap = new SoapClient('https://apiserver.com');

        // HAAL STUDENTEN OP VIA API CALL     
        $result = $this->soap-someOtherApiFunction($this->webservicesPwd,3,1);

        // INDIEN RESULTAAT NIET CORRECT
      if(is_int($result)) {

           throw new \Exception($errorMessage);
        }


        dd($result);
    }
```

Comment: Are they in the same class? If so, then you can create a function that creates the soap and returns it, or create a function that both creates the soap and calls the SOAP method you're trying to call. If it's not in the same class, then you can create a new class for the SOAP that creates the soap and calls the method.

Comment: What about a repository pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class:

```
class ApiNameClient {
    protected $soapClient;

    protected $webservicesPwd;

    public function __construct() {
    // initialize $soapClient and $webservicesPwd here
    }

    public function getStudents() {
        $result = $this->soapClient->myFirstAction($this->webservicesPwd,3,1);

        return $this->defendInteger($result);
    }

    protected function defendInteger($value) {
        if(is_int($value)) {
            throw new \Exception($errorMessage);
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```